# Como trocar de páginas através do nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Bom, tentei trocar de página apertar no botão entrar, mas recebo este erro:

> ```
> "path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile".
> ```

Minha estrutura de pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formulário HTML (index.html):

```html
  <div class="bg-modal">
      <form action="/login" class="login-form" method="post">
        <h1>Entrar</h1>
        <div id="close" class="close">+</div>

        <div class="txtb">
          <input type="text">
          <span data-placeholder="RA"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="txtb">
          <input type="password">
          <span data-placeholder="Senha"></span>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="logbtn" value="Entrar">

        <div class="bottom-text">
          Não possuí conta? <a id="botaoRegistrar" href="#corpoForm">Crie sua Conta</a>
        </div>

      </form>
  </div>
```

rotas.js:

```
//var AlunoDao = require('../app/aluno-dao');
var conexao = require('../config/custom-mssql');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('dashboard.html');
    });
    app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
        console.log("FUNCIONOU");
        res.sendFile('index.html');
    });
}
```

custom-express.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const rotas = require('../app/rotas.js');


// informar o express que vamos usar o EJS como engine de visualização
//app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// informar o express que vamos usar os módulos relacionados às variaveis abaixo
//app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use(express.static('views')); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//acrescentando informacoes de cabecalho para suportar o CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE");
    next();
  });

// passar como parâmetro para o módulo rotas.js
rotas(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Ao entrar em `localhost:3000` é carregado o `index.html` (funciona), mas após apertar no botão `entrar` ele cai no método `app.post(...)`, mas não consegue renderizar o `dashboard.html`.

Tentei substituir o `res.sendFile('index.html')` por `res.sendFile('dashboard.html')`, e ele continua renderizando o `index.html`. Como isso é possível?

Comment: Na documentação do [Express](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.sendFile):"A menos que a opção root esteja definida no objeto options, path deve ser um caminho absoluto para o arquivo."

Comment: Desculpa, poderia ser mais claro, não entendi muito bem

Comment: Dá uma olhada no link que lhe passei. Lá está dizendo que você tem que criar um objeto `options` com a propriedade `root` setada para o diretório que será raiz para caminhos relativos. Use esse objeto `options` como segundo parâmetro para `res.sendFile()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você não entendeu o que o Augusto Vasques comentou, resolva desta maneira:

No seu código de rota para o `post`, passe um objeto como segundo argumento com o atributo `root` definindo o caminho absoluto para saber qual arquivo HTML deve ser enviado.

Ficaria assim:

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log("FUNCIONOU");
    res.sendFile('dashboard.html', {
      root: path.join(__dirname , 'views')
    });
});
```

Feito isso, o express sabera qual arquivo e onde este arquivo esta para ser enviado na resposta.